# Shutdown as if ctrl+c was entered

Tags: c#, .net, console-application, .net-6.0

I'm trying to shutdown a process a bit more gracefully than what the `process.Kill(true)`, method does.

I have a console application, where I start start another process "myProcess" (which is not an application I have sourcecode for), which I want to be able to shutdown, as if pressing `ctrl+c` in the console.
"myProcess" is essentially pinging a receiver at a fixed interval.

When I shut it down using `ctrl+c` the "myProcess" shuts down gracefully, sending an "i am offline now" request to a receiver.
However, when I shut it down using `kill(true)`, it doesn't get to send the offline request, and the receiver stops receiving pings, but doesn't mark it as online.

Note I don't have control over the source for myProcess nor the receiver, so I can't change any behaviour in those.

I have tried using `waitForExit()`, `waitForExit(0)` and `kill()`, all of which only stops my debugging session, but myProcess keeps running.

Searching for a solution I come across answers suggestion these methods, and using `GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent`, to send the `ctrl+c` event programmatically. However my console app does not recognize that method, and I can't seem to find any way to use it.
I assume, because the answers were fairly old, that it is no longer an option in .NET 6.

Does anyone know, how to shutdown a process gracefully, wither a spawned chilprocess, or the self process `Process.GetCurrentProcess()`?

Comment: https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.generateconsolectrlevent

Comment: `Ctrl+C` is the equivalent of SIGINT in Linux while Kill is a SIGTERM. [.NET Core added handling of SIGINT](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/50527) but didn't change `Process` to include a `Break` method. The equivalent events on Windows are CTRL_C_EVENT and CTRL_BREAK_EVENT , while the equivalent of SIGTERM are `CTRL_SHUTDOWN_EVENT` and `CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT`

Comment: @HansPassant Using the dllImport described in your linked solved it for me. If you put it into an answer i can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks something that needs handling of SIGTERMS.

Check [this out](https://medium.com/@rainer_8955/gracefully-shutdown-c-apps-2e9711215f6d)

Comment: This looks like it handles receiving SIGTERMS, i'm looking for a way to trigger them from code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [CloseMainWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.closemainwindow?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-6.0#System_Diagnostics_Process_CloseMainWindow), read the docs to see if it is suitable for your use case.

Comment: CloseMainWindow has the same effect as WaitForExit, and kill()